# PHP function polymorphism

Tags: php

I would like to use function polymorphism in my [PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP) classes. I intend to check the input type of a function for some of my children classes functions.

```
class A
{
    public function setValue(Type $value)
    {
    }
}

class B extends A
{
    public function setValue(XType $value)
    {
    }
}

class C extends A
{
    public function setValue(ZType $value)
    {
    }
}
$b = new B();
$b->setValue(new XType());
```

with

```
class Type {};
class XType extends Type;
class ZType extends Type;
```

The behavior I am looking for is that PHP throws an exception if *setValue* is called with the wrong argument type.

If I use the above code, I get an error:

> Runtime Notice: Declaration of B::setValue() should be compatible with A::setValue(Type $value) in B.php line ..

This is how I managed to obtain the behavior I wanted:

```
class B extends A
{
    public function setValue(Type $value)
    {
        if (!$value instanceof XType) {
            throw new \Exception("value $value not allowed, should be of type XType");
        parent::setValue($value);
        }
    }
}
```

But I would be glad to let the PHP core handle that bit of code for me :)

I see that I was **not** clear enough..

I am trying to provide the caller with a default behavior, *A::setValue()*, and with a specific behaviour regarding certain child classes, *B::setValue()*, so if the caller tries to call *B::setValue()* with an unsupported type, it will get an error, but if it calls, let's say, *D::setValue()*, it will get the default, *A::setValue()*.

Comment: Lol, Yes ! I would like to know if there is a way to achieve the same behavior I managed to get without the instanceof part :)

Comment: Method parameter types are contravariant.

Answer (score 1):

What you have already works, there's no need for the `instanceof` check you're doing. You can just declare the type in the argument type hint.

What is wrong with your code is that it's not proper polymorphism. That is also what the notice (note: not *error*) wants to tell you. Your subclasses require a different type of argument than the parent class. Even if those types are related, it means you cannot substitute one of the child classes for any given instance of the parent class. That is what is breaking polymorphism. If your child classes require a more specialized type, their declaration is not compatible with their parent anymore and hence they're not entirely polymorphic.

In proper polymorphism, this should work:

```
if (rand(0, 1)) {
    $obj = new A;
} else {
    $obj = new B;
}

$obj->setValue(new Type);
```

With what you're trying to do it would not work.

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean... I should be more specific about my need, I will edit my question, thank you !

Comment: I understood what you're trying to do, but there's no real difference in the answer. :) You should *not* narrow or alter the type a function accepts in its children. I understand that's an easy temptation, but ask yourself why you're doing this. You're explicitly making certain classes depend on certain other classes. That's two inheritance chains being coupled together. If they're that closely related, why aren't they in the same class or otherwise explicitly coupled to begin with? Maybe there's a legitimate use case for this, but think first if that's really needed.

Comment: I did not declare the type in the class because the Type is used in different classes.. To let you understand what I am trying to achieve, go have a look at http://www.graphviz.org/content/attrs I am trying to map all attributes and attributes types to OO style classes. 
Attributes represent my classes A, B, C and attributes types the XType, YType, etc. I want to make sure that A is using the proper Type

Comment: Why do you differentiate between "attributes" and "attribute types" as two separate class hierarchies? Seems to me that an attribute *is* a type. You could have a number of different `abstract` parent classes which represent types (`Double`, `ArrowType`, ...) and have concrete attributes `extend` those types (`Damping extends Double`, `Arrowtail extends ArrowType`). That would seem to model the requirement much better.

Comment: I neither thought about it! I will give it a try and let you know if that suits my needs